# What SPSS analysis to use to compare stress and anxiety in two different time points?

Tags: repeated-measures, spss, psychology

I want to analyze my data related to two different timelines -  measuring stress and anxiety in two different time points:
time point 1 before meeting dogs, time point 2 after meeting dogs.

Then I would compare the data of both time points with each other.

What SPSS analysis  should I use for this?

Comment: Hi. Please try to make an apt title that articulates your query (I have done it for you this time).

Answer (score 1):

You could use a paired samples t test to compare the sample means across time.